# CodeIgniter - Create multiple databases from master SQL file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

What would be the best way to take an .sql file that includes schema and table creation statements and use it to create new databases from within CodeIgniter? What I want to be able to do is use this .sql file as a blueprint for several databases with the same schema, but which may be created at any time.

I imagine I just need to be able to take this file, extract the contents and echo it out into a database query. Is there a better way to do it?

I also need to be able to inject a custom database name into the statements before submitting the query. How would I go about this? Just have a placeholder keyword and do a preg replace with the database name?

Just to ensure all databases are maintained synchronously, I thought perhaps this blueprint schema should be added to CodeIgniter as a module. That way if I need to alter the schema, I can upload a new version of the module with the updated .sql file and perform the necessary migrations across all the databases. Sound reasonable? If so, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this (run a .sql file) before, and I used this;

```
$sql = read_file('path/to/file.sql');

$final = '';
foreach(explode("\n", $sql) as $line)
{
      if ( isset($line[0]) && $line[0] != '#' )
      {
                $final .= $line . "\n";
      }
}

foreach (explode(";\n", final) as $sql)
{
      if ($sql)
      {
                $this->db->query($sql);
      }
}
```

Comment: Looks good as far as reading the file goes. I guess if I need to inject the database name I can just do a str_replace on each line, right? What about database alterations? I imagine I'd have to just run the statements that alter the tables and then upload a new master .sql file for subsequent databases?

Comment: Maybe the CI Migration Class could help you? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/migration.html

Comment: Yeah migrations would work for that I suppose, I'm just always trying to reduce risk by not having to maintain two things (migrations and the updated master .sql file). I try to use the CI classes as much as possible, but for the database creation the DB Forge class just seemed a bit limited (from what I could see) and it's much more convenient to just use the .sql exported from Workbench.